# What is the "registry editing" equivalent to disabling Windows-7 startup programs with MSCONFIG

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-registry, msconfig

Startup programs in Windows 7 can be defined in several different locations:

- User "Start Up" folder
- System "Start Up" folder
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- and so on...

`MSCONFIG`, a Microsoft tool, is a good first step to disabling these startup programs that are only defined in the registry itself.

My question now is:

What is the equivalent operation when "manually" editing the registry for **disabling** startup programs via MSCONFIG?

[image]

I know this much ... the answer is **NOT** deleting entries from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run or any other of these locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`msconfig` stores its configuration in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig`. The sub key `startupreg` contains information about the (location=) registry startup entries that you disabled, the sub key `startupfolder` contains information about the (location=) folder startup entries.

Answer (score 0):

when u use msconfig, the reg entries r **moved** to the msconfig area of the registry, therefore deleting them from the RUN key. If u never want to activate the program again, deleting them from RUN is not an issue.